# Remove HTML from String - RSS

Tags: java, html, regex, parsing, rss

I'm currently building a RSS-Reader and some websites have weird rss-2.0-files which I have to modify first to display them.

One of them is [seen here:](http://rss.golem.de/rss.php?feed=RSS2.0)

The problem is that the description tag does not only contain the description text but also some

html-elements like `<a href ... />` `<img src ... />`

How can I remove all these unnecessary information without looking for every single attribute?

Is there something in Java available? Or is a regular expression useful in this case?

Comment: Ignore all inside CDATA <content:encoded><![CDATA[...

Comment: well, this was easy :D - if you create a response I'll mark it as resolved ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore all inside CDATA such as

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex to remove HTML tag:

```
String noHtml = html.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
```

Even though, I'd use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse HTML code in Java.

Comment: What's the first "\\" for ? `<>` aren't special by their own as far as I know